# Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)

Tags: ios, flutter

Here I am trying to use flutter to build IOS app and trying to use HTTP requests and flutter asks us to add [these codes in info plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTtp2.png) and I did add them [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cDsg.png) but is shows error **"Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)"**

Answer (score 0):

> check below example, you can use like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>FluxStore</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```